# ipython notebook in a new broswer window (and not a new tab in an existing window)

Tags: window, jupyter-notebook

so I've been talked into ipython notebook. I even set a shortcut (should be added to the beginners guides: alias ipn='ipython notebook --pylab inline &') but it opens a new tab in an open browsing session. 
I'd like it to start the ipython in a NEW window. How do I do that?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> alias ipn='ipython notebook --pylab inline

But the dev team recommend not to start with `--pylab` it leads to bugs for newcommers that do not know what pylab really does :-(. It is better to use `%matplotlib inline` at beginning of notebooks ! (explicit is better than implicit)

As for opening in a new window, IPython rely on `webbrowser.open` in `notebookapp.py` line `711` on master. And the ability to choose new tab or new window is not configurable. (You can try to open an issue or a Pull request on github, but it might fall in the "to little use case to make it configurable")

Cannot you just 'detach' the current tab ?

Comment: I detached the tab, but was wondering if it could be incorporated to the cmd somehow...